# Vala doesn't free global data?

Tags: vala

Have a simple code:

```
class Global
{
    ~Global() { stdout.printf("~Global"); }
}

class Local
{
    ~Local() { stdout.printf("~Local"); }
}

Global global;

static int main()
{
    global = new Global();
    var local = new Local();

    return 0;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
~Local
```

So only local data has been freed.

How to free global data?

Should I use pointers or there is more simple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `global = null` to your program. The reference count will drop to zero and the variable will be freed.

Be aware that global data is usually a bad idea.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I decided to delete global data manually using pointers, it works too.